# creating objects of particular class in R

Tags: r

Function lm(...) returns an object of class 'lm'. How do I create an array of such objects? I want to do the following:

```
my_lm_array <- rep(as.lm(NULL), 20)
#### next, populate this array by running lm() repeatedly:
for(i in 1:20) {
   my_lm_array[i] <- lm(my_data$results ~ my_data[i,])
}
```

Obviously the line "my_lm <- rep(as.lm(NULL), 20)" does not work. I'm trying to create an array of objects of type 'lm'. How do I do that?

Comment: Is it really `my_data[i,]` in your `lm` call, not `my_data[,i]` ?

Comment: Since you obviously are talking about a single dimensioned object (really a non-dimensioned one in fact) then you should avoid using the word "array" which as a specific meaning in R syntax.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right (I'm still relatively new with R).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it will answer your question, but if what you want to do is run a series of `lm` from a variable against different columns of a data frame, you can do something like this :

```
data <- data.frame(result=rnorm(10), v1=rnorm(10), v2=rnorm(10))
my_lms <- lapply(data[,c("v1","v2")], function(v) {
  lm(data$result ~ v)
})
```

Then, `my_lms` would be a list of elements of class `lm`.

Comment: I see what this is doing. Let me try it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you *can* create an array of empty/meaningless `lm` objects as follows:

```
z <- NA
class(z) <- "lm"
lm_array <- replicate(20,z,simplify=FALSE)
```

but that's probably not the best way to solve the problem.  You could just create an empty list of the appropriate length (`vector("list",20)`) and fill in the elements as you go along: R is weakly enough typed that it won't mind you replacing `NULL` values with `lm` objects. More idiomatically, though, you can run `lapply` on your list of predictor names:

```
my_data <- data.frame(result=rnorm(10), v1=rnorm(10), v2=rnorm(10))
prednames <- setdiff(names(my_data),"result")  ## extract predictor names
lapply(prednames,
 function(n) lm(reformulate(n,response="result"),
                 data=my_data))
```

Or, if you don't feel like creating an anonymous function, you can first generate a list of formulae (using `lapply`) and then run `lm` on them:

```
formList <- lapply(prednames,reformulate,response="result") ## create formulae
lapply(formList,lm,data=my_data)  ## run lm() on each formula in turn
```

will create the same list of `lm` objects as the first strategy above.

In general it is good practice to avoid using syntax such as `my_data$result` inside modeling formulae; instead, try to set things up so that all the variables in the model are drawn from inside the `data` object.  That way methods like `predict` and `update` are more likely to work correctly ...